# Nav bar with css grid won't align

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I'm trying to make a simple nav bar with the logo on the right and the menu and search option on the left. However I cannot figure out how to vertically align them. I feel like this has probably an easy fix but I just can't figure it out. It's for a school asignment.

Here's my html & css

```css
.main-nav {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbardesk {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "logo links search";
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(141, 125, 31, 0.9);
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  grid-area: logo;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}

.main-nav {
  grid-area: links;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.searchicon {
  grid-area: search;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbardesk v-align">
  <h1 class="logo">Buurtsuper Leo van der Drift</h1>

  <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Over ons</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Kantoren en bedrijven</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Bestellen</a></li>
    <li class="nav-links social"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
  </ul>

  <i class="fas fa-search searchicon"></i>
</div>
```

it currently looks like this

[image]

and I want it to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove h1 and ul margin and try the snippet below.

```css
.main-nav {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbardesk {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "logo links search";
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(141, 125, 31, 0.9);
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  grid-area: logo;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  border: solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  grid-area: links;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid;
  margin: 0;
  
}

.searchicon {
  grid-area: search;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbardesk v-align">
  <h1 class="logo">Buurtsuper Leo van der Drift</h1>

  <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Over ons</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Kantoren en bedrijven</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Bestellen</a></li>
    <li class="nav-links social"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
  </ul>

  <i class="fas fa-search searchicon"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce the error given the code you have provided but adding `align-items:center;` should do what you want.

```
    .navbardesk{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "logo links search";
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    background-color: rgba(141,125,31,0.9);    
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure, your li, a tag should be display: inline-block it will not work margin, padding in inline display.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will produce exactly what you are looking for, may be some tweaking you still need depending on your situation

```
#js-menu {

    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,200px);
    background-color: #f3f3ec;
    justify-items: end;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;

}
```

put this line of code along with your other css. there are many ways around!